# Why is wavelength of an electromagnetic wave so much loner than what my scope shows?

Tags: electromagnetism, wavelength

I made a simple LC Tank circuit which oscillates at 166 kHz. Looking at it using my oscilloscope I can see one cycle of the sine wave takes about 6 microseconds.

Now if I stick and antenna to this I should be ale to emit electromagnetic waves at 166 kHz frequency which has a wavelength of about `1.8` kilometres!

How can we have such a long wavelength if one cycle of this oscillation is only 6 microseconds? it doesn't make sense to me. Do the EM waves not get generated in the same speed as the oscillation in the antenna?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Light travels quickly, that's all. In 6 $\mu$s, light travels $1.8$ km, so by the time you've finished one cycle, that's how far the radiation emitted during the start of that cycle has propagated.

Comment: ah that makes sense.